Bluettoth Speaker Connects and then Disconnects; Ubuntu 24 identifies it incorrectly as Keyboard
I wanted to connect a bluetooth speaker to Ubuntu 24.04.1. Using blueman interface (as well as bluetoothctl) the speaker would connect briefly before disconnecting. This disconnection was unexpected.
==> /var/log/auth.log <==
2024-09-09T10:09:03.194971+09:30 webb systemd-logind[1272]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event23 (LG SN5Y(3F) (AVRCP))

==> /var/log/kern.log <==
2024-09-09T10:09:03.165441+09:30 webb kernel: input: LG SN5Y(3F) (AVRCP) as /devices/virtual/input/input29

==> /var/log/syslog <==
2024-09-09T10:09:03.165441+09:30 webb kernel: input: LG SN5Y(3F) (AVRCP) as /devices/virtual/input/input29

==> /var/log/Xorg.0.log <==
[ 374.839] (II) config/udev: Adding input device LG SN5Y(3F) (AVRCP) (/dev/input/event23)
[ 374.839] (**) LG SN5Y(3F) (AVRCP): Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[ 374.839] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'LG SN5Y(3F) (AVRCP)'
[ 374.839] (**) LG SN5Y(3F) (AVRCP): always reports core events
[ 374.839] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event23"
[ 374.839] (II) event23 - LG SN5Y(3F) (AVRCP): is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 374.839] (II) event23 - LG SN5Y(3F) (AVRCP): device is a keyboard
[ 374.840] (II) event23 - LG SN5Y(3F) (AVRCP): device removed
[ 374.856] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/input/input29/event23"
[ 374.856] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "LG SN5Y(3F) (AVRCP)" (type: KEYBOARD, id 18)
[ 374.856] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[ 374.856] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[ 374.856] (WW) Option "xkb_variant" requires a string value
[ 374.856] (WW) Option "xkb_options" requires a string value
[ 374.856] (II) event23 - LG SN5Y(3F) (AVRCP): is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 374.857] (II) event23 - LG SN5Y(3F) (AVRCP): device is a keyboard

==> /var/log/auth.log <==
2024-09-09T10:09:06.143829+09:30 webb dbus-daemon[1249]: [system] Rejected send message, 0 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.54" (uid=1000 pid=2223 comm="/usr/bin/wireplumber" label="unconfined") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.6" (uid=0 pid=1247 comm="/usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd" label="unconfined")

==> /var/log/Xorg.0.log <==
[ 377.795] (II) event23 - LG SN5Y(3F) (AVRCP): device removed
[ 377.804] (II) config/udev: removing device LG SN5Y(3F) (AVRCP)
[ 377.805] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"

Ubuntu was incorrectly identifying the device as keyboard when it was a speaker.

Ubuntu 24 would identify the OS as Ubuntu Core, the only version of Ubuntu to use a single digit version. If this is the version of Ubuntu you are using the tag is wrong if this is not the version please edit the question and fix the version info. Yes the version info is important.
